# How to create specific pages for resources in my web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering what the best approach would be to create dynamic webpages based on data I have available?

I have a page which shows a table with information about certain countries, but there is more information I would like to show. What I want to achieve is that the user looks at the table and finds a land they want to know more about. When the user clicks on the country name for example, a new page should open with the data I provide. How to open a new page and all that is not what I'm asking for, but more how I would go about to achieve dynamically creating a html-page based on what the user clicks.

I have data on 150 countries, so I want to able to create the country specific pages on the fly, not manually creating 150 html-pages for the countries.

I hope that was clear enough, if not, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to look into database based application probably, or have a system read the data of files depending on the format you use and use a dynamic language. Especially if you are using multiple files. If you had just one HTML with all your data you could do a single JS app.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I'm not sure about what to Google for though, so I hope that if anyone here have any suggestions they will provide them :)

Comment: PHP is easy enough, but if you know JS already node can do the job too. I found sails.js to be an easy way to get a back end sorted and serving data. It also contain a template engine which can be use to create a template which will use loaded data.

Comment: I will have a look at sails.js and Node.js. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use php and mysql.

- add your countries in mysql
- add data for each country in mysql
- make html page table with all the countries and links for each country that send the viewer to page something like moreinfo.php?country=1
- make the moreinfo.php page ,which depend on the number for country=
- it will display the certain data

If you cant use php then you have to create files (pages) with the data for each country and on moreinfo.html execute javascript that will read the content of each file